# Why list Yehoshua before Kalev?

Tags: parashat-shelach, meraglim-spies, yehoshua-joshua, kaleb-caleb

When the 12 spies are listed in Bamidbar 13:4 their order, according to [Ramban](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.4?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en) is based on the personal qualities of the individuals. Kaleiv is listed third and Yehoshua is listed fifth.

After the 10 spies make their negative report, Kaleiv (in pasuk 30) gets up to ostensibly agree but then he disagrees with their report. Yehoshua stays silent (dealt with by the [Ha'amek Davar](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.13.30?lang=bi&with=Haamek%20Davar&lang2=en)). **But later (14:6), when they rip their clothing, Yehoshua is listed first.**

Continuing, a special mention is made of Kaleiv's spirit (in 14:24) and then in pasuk 30, Kaleiv is mentioned first (and the Ibn Ezra [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.14.30?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) that he is mentioned first here because he was the one who silenced the people initially).

Why, in the middle moment, was Yehoshua listed before Kaleiv? Do we assume that in this case, he ripped his clothing first so this is a simple chronological statement or is there some other reason for the inversion of the order which appears in other cases?

Comment: Note when they're mentioned in the same verse Yehoshua is always listed first, except for one time, to teach you that they were of equal stature ([Tosefta Kerisos 4:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosefta_Keritot.4.7)).